# Hide div if does not have HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, its supposed to reorder my `div`s within `#list`. And it does that just fine. Now what I want to add is: if a div does not have the attribute "data-l-disc" don't add it/hide it.

```html
<select id="selectid">
  <option id="valid1" value="def">Default order</option>
  <option id="valid2" value="hl">h-l</option>
</select>
<div id="list">
---------the follow div is used about 50*-------------
 <div class="dbl" data-l-disc="1">
 ---------blabla (like 10 other divs are in here)----------
 </div>


</div>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    if(document.getElementById('selectid').value == "hl") {
      var dList = $(".dbl");
      dList.sort(function(a, b){ return $(b).data("l-disc")-$(a).data("l-disc")});
      $("#list").html(dList);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by have a "tag"? Do you mean [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Attribute)?  `<div>` is a [tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/tag); if you had the tag `<div data-l-disc="something">`, the `data-l-disc="something"` part is an attribute.

Comment: thnx,  i ment attribute then ;)

Comment: An example of the structure of `#list` would help in answering your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can hide it by using

```
$(".dbl").not("[data-l-disc]").hide()
```

Comment: awesome that worked,  now i got a follow up question.the complete code has like 20 attributes/20 different filters. now if i run this  the div stays hidden even if i select another option. is there a simple way i can say (each time the code is run)  select all 'attributes' again,  then re-filter with that specific code?

Comment: it's better to ask this question as another question

Comment: solved that issue by using your code but with  .filter and.show,  all my divs had 1 attribute in commen so used that